# C unicode to ascii

Tags: c, http, unicode, ascii

I want to convert in C a string that is in unicode to ascii.
My problem is that I'm trying to find in the tcp payload of a packet the string POST of a packet but I can't find it because probably it's utf-8 encoded. 
I know that there are more unicode characters of ascii one but I think that the problem is that..
I've found something for C# but do you know if exist something for C?

Comment: What do you want done with characters which are not ASCII?

Comment: What's the problem with keeping it as UTF-8? It's pretty much the _de facto_ standard for the web.

Comment: I don't mind of that characters.. I need only the string "POST".

Comment: this is because my program looks for http packets and checks what type of packet is.. but if the packet is encoded I can't..

Comment: If the data is supposed to be an HTTP POST packet and you cannot see the text you expect then I believe you have an entirely different problem that the one you are attempting to solve.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for "POST", this is the advantage of UTF-8. ASCII strings in UTF-8 are only represented by themselves.

Comment: uhm so you are saying that is not possible to find the POST?

Comment: I succeed finding the GET requests.. I need to do the same with the POSTs

Comment: @user546285: The string "POST" is exactly the same in UTF8 as it is in ASCII, as @Joshua is saying. So if you search for that it should be fine. Perhaps there is some other issue? e.g. maybe the string is split between two packets?

Comment: uhm so I should see the "normal" characters like POST in there.. ok, maybe then there is another problem but I don't think is the one that you are saying because POST is always in the first packet..

Comment: Yes, you have another problem with your code. The HTTP request is always ASCII which also happens to be UTF-8 because all ASCII is valid UTF-8.

Comment: @cenos: Then either the string is not there to find, or it is not UTF-8 encoded.  Perhaps you could post a hex-dump of the data you are processing?

Comment: 0e2e550 is from one packet of 538 bytes

Comment: @cenos: I meant you should update the question with the data, not add a comment!  And why only 7 digits (3.5 bytes!) - what could we devise from that?.  Use your debugger's memory dump to output the data - in most debuggers that will include ASCII data alongside the hex; if the encoding is UTF-8 and the string "POST" is in there, you'll see it.  If not then you are wasting your time until you figure out the encoding.